# PHP form will not post

Tags: php, mysql, forms, post

I have just implemented mysql_real_escape_string() and now my script won't write to the DB. Everything worked fine before adding mysql_real_escape_string():

Any ideas??

```
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
$description = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['description']);
$custid = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['customerid']);

mysql_send("INSERT INTO list 
              SET id = '',  
                  name = '$name', 
                  description = '$description', 
                  custid = '$custid' ");
```

Comment: What is mysql_send?
Are there any error's being reported? What does the query look like before it's being sent to mysql (try to echo it out)?

Comment: Debugging tip: Place the SQL statement in a variable, i.e., `$sql = "INSERT INTO list SET id = '',  name = '$name'"` etc... then `echo $sql` (or `die($sql)`). This may shed some light on what's causing the problem. Also, how are you connecting to the database, yourself or through some sort of 3rd party api? If the latter, perhaps there is a method the api recommends for escaping data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what is that mysql_**send** function?
what if to change it to mysql_query();

Comment: OP said it was working until he started using mysql_real_escape_string. He didn't say he was changed that line of code.

Answer (score 1):

It should be easy to figure out what's going on.

Fist, instead of sending the query you're constructing to the database, echo it out (or log it), and see what you're actually sending to the database.

If that doesn't make it obvious, see what mysql_error() has to say.

Answer (score 0):

mysql_real_escape_string should have a database connection passed as the second argument since it asks the database what characters need to be escaped.

```
$connection = mysql_connect(HOST, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
$cleanstring = mysql_real_escape_string("my string", $connection);
```

Comment: @blockhead, I was about to say that. You may be confused with mysqli_real_escape_string, which needs its first argument to be a link to the database.

Comment: In some cases it gets confused (like if you have more than one connection open), I've had this problem a number of times.  I always pass a connection to ensure the string isn't truncated/erased.

Comment: Hello MySQLi, it's nice of you for carrying the database connection with you the whole time (OO style)

Answer (score 0):

A typical failure on understanding how to use certain functions...
You're just using mysql_real_escape_string on raw input data. Have you ever heard of santizing / validating input? `mysql_real_escape_string` does not make sense on numbers. If you've validated a variable to be a number, you don't need to escape it.

mysql_send is an alias for mysql_query right?
Use debug code, add `echo mysql_error();` after `mysql_send(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
       mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "password") or die(mysql_error());
       mysql_select_db("database") or die(mysql_error());
       $name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
       $description = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['description']);   
       $custid = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['customerid']);

       //If you doing Update use this code
       mysql_query("UPDATE list SET id = '', name = '$name', description = '$description' WHERE custid = '$custid' ") or die(mysql_error());
       //OR if you doing Insert use this  code.
       mysql_query("INSERT INTO list(name, description, custid) VALUES('$name', '$description', '$custid')") or die(mysql_error());
       //If custid is Integer type user $custid instead of '$custid'.
```

If you are updating the records in the list table based on the custid use the UPDATE command OR if you are insertinf the records into list table use INSERT command.